# Write to csv in GO error

Tags: csv, go

I am trying to write to a csv file in GO using the standard library "encoding/csv" that comes with GO. However, nothing is being written to the file and there are no errors returning either. Below is the writing code. The values in the map are string arrays. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
func writeErrors() {

    file, error := os.OpenFile("output.csv", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0666 )

    if error != nil {panic(error)}
    defer file.Close()

    // New Csv writer
    writer := csv.NewWriter(file)

    // Headers
    var new_headers = []string { "group_id", "account_id", "location_id", "payment_rating", "records_with_error" }
    returnError := writer.Write(new_headers)
    if returnError != nil {
        fmt.Println(returnError)
    }

    for key, value := range errors {
        returnError := writer.Write(value)
        if returnError != nil {
            fmt.Println(returnError)
        }
        fmt.Println("Writing: ", key, value)
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need the `file, error := os.OpenFile("output.csv", os.O_APPEND, 0666 )` line?

Comment: I added that because i needed to be able to append to file, and as I understand it when files are created or opened they are set for read access only.

Comment: I guess i can add on |os.O_CREATE if the file does not exist too and skip creating it.

Comment: `os.Create` will open a writeable file.

Comment: I wrote a nice package to handle CSV like JSON in Go: https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an additional flag, as you are calling os.OpenFile directly instead of via os.Create which passes O_RDWR for you. you need to either pass O_RDWR or O_WRONLY along with your O_APPEND | O_CREATE flags.

O_APPEND is only used to say that writes should be appended to the end of the file when writing, it doesn't specify the open mode itself.

Additional Note:
you're using "error" as a variable name, this is actually a type in Go, the idiom generally used for naming the error return variable is "err"

Answer (score 8):

You need to call `writer.Flush()` after `writer.Write()`

```
//from package documentation

func (w *Writer) Flush()
Flush writes any buffered data to the underlying io.Writer.
```

Answer (score 3):

`os.Create` opens a writeable file as can be learned from the [source](http://golang.org/src/pkg/os/file.go?s=7058:7106#L228) and the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Create)